# Is Option wrapping a value a good pattern?

Tags: scala

I recently wrote the following bit of Scala:

```
val f: File = ... // pretend this file came from somewhere
val foo = toFoo(io.Source.fromFile(f).mkString)
```

I really didn't like the way this flowed.  To understand what's happening, you have to start with `f` in the middle, read left to `fromFile`, read right to `mkString`, read left again to `toFoo`.  Ugh.

Especially after getting used to functional transformations of sequences, this is difficult to read.  My next attempt looks like this:

```
val foo = Some(f)
  .map(io.Source.fromFile)
  .map(_.mkString)
  .map(toFoo)
  .get
```

I like the flow of this much better.  You can see what happens Is this a good use of the `Option` class?  Or am I abusing it?  Is there a better pattern that I can use to achieve the same flow?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is perfectly okay.  However, there is a method `|>` in [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) that does one better, and you can create it yourself if you don't want all of Scalaz:

```
class Piper[A](a: A) { def |>[B](f: A => B) = f(a) }
implicit def pipe_everything[A](a: A) = new Piper(a)

f |> io.Source.fromFile |> {_.mkString} |> toFoo
```

Personally, I tend to write a lot of code that requires parentheses and I like methods better than operators in most cases, so in my code I normally call `|>` "use", but it's the same deal:

```
f.use(io.Source.fromFile).use(_.mkString).use(toFoo)
```

---

In Scala 2.11 or later, you can get the same behavior and improved performance with (slightly) less syntax:

```
implicit class Piper[A](private val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def |>[B](f: A => B) = f(a)
}
```

Comment: it's a snippet that I drop into every project I write! Should be in the standard library really...

Comment: @Kevin - Agreed, it should be in the standard library.  I also have it in all my projects since I have a standard library that I drop into every project I write, and this is one of the things in it.

Comment: An updated version for the current generation: `implicit class Piper[A](a: A) { def |>[B](f: A=>B) = f(a) } extends AnyVal`

Comment: @KevinWright - you missed a `private val`, but it's a good point and I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have no problems with the other answers given here, but did you consider changing the name of toFoo into something that 'flows' better? I mean, toFoo really smells like something that should be on the *right* of an expression, but if you rename it into something else, it might fit on the *left* as well.

```
// toFoo, as defined by you
val foo = toFoo(io.Source.fromFile(f).mkString)
// Same function, different name
val foo = createFooFrom(io.Source.fromFile(f).mkString)
```

Comment: Agreed, but is was just an example :-)

Answer (score 4):

You add `toFoo` to `String` through the pimp my library pattern. Then it becomes:

```
val foo = Source fromFile f mkString () toFoo
```

Comment: Or `(Source fromFile f mkString) toFoo`, just personal preference though.

Comment: @Kevin I wish there was a symbol that could stand for "no parameter list". If it were mandatory, it would solve all of postfix notation problems.