# Ternary Operator Similar To ?:

Tags: scala

I am trying to avoid constructs like this:

```
val result = this.getClass.getSimpleName
if (result.endsWith("$")) result.init else result
```

Ok, in this example the `then` and `else` branch are simple, but you can image complex ones.
I built the following:

```
object TernaryOp {
  class Ternary[T](t: T) {
    def is[R](bte: BranchThenElse[T,R]) = if (bte.branch(t)) bte.then(t) else bte.elze(t)
  }
  class Branch[T](branch: T => Boolean) {
    def ?[R] (then: T => R) = new BranchThen(branch,then)
  }
  class BranchThen[T,R](val branch: T => Boolean, val then: T => R)
  class Elze[T,R](elze: T => R) {
    def :: (bt: BranchThen[T,R]) = new BranchThenElse(bt.branch,bt.then,elze)
  }
  class BranchThenElse[T,R](val branch: T => Boolean, val then: T => R, val elze: T => R)
  implicit def any2Ternary[T](t: T) = new Ternary(t)
  implicit def fct2Branch[T](branch: T => Boolean) = new Branch(branch)
  implicit def fct2Elze[T,R](elze: T => R) = new Elze(elze)
}
```

Defined that, I can replace the above simple example with:

```
this.getClass.getSimpleName is {s: String => s.endsWith("$")} ? {s: String => s.init} :: {s: String => s}
```

But how can I get rid of the `s: String =>`? I want something like that:

```
this.getClass.getSimpleName is {_.endsWith("$")} ? {_.init} :: {identity}
```

I guess the compiler needs the extra stuff to infer types.

Comment: Since I didn't actually have this in my answer--the reason you're having trouble is that type inference works best from left to right, but you're binding your tokens together from right to left because of operator precedence.  If you make all of your statements words (with the same precedence) and change the way things group together, you'll get the inference that you want.  (I.e. you would have `HasIs`, `IsWithCondition`, `ConditionAndTrueCase` classes that would build up parts of the expression from left to right.)

Comment: I unconsciously presumed the way of type inference from left to right, but stucked with operator precedence and associativity of method names, especially starting with `?` before any other alphanum char as a method name first char and a `:` for left associativity. So I have to rethink of new method names to get type inference working from left to right. thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We can combine [How to define a ternary operator in Scala which preserves leading tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705920) with the answer to [Is Option wrapping a value a good pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889281) to get

```
scala>   "Hi".getClass.getSimpleName |> {x => x.endsWith("$") ? x.init | x}
res0: String = String

scala> List.getClass.getSimpleName |> {x => x.endsWith("$") ? x.init | x}
res1: String = List
```

Is this adequate for your needs?

Comment: Thats very close to what I have in mind. nice approach. I´ll think about that. My reason to avoid the very first code was to be more concise in not having a temporary `val` for a following `if`-statement: Do it intelligible in one line, just like one have it in mind.

Answer (score 127):

From [Tony Morris' Lambda Blog](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/does-scala-have-javas-ternary-operator/):

> I hear this question a lot. Yes it does. Instead of `c ? p : q`, it is
>   written `if(c) p else q`.
>
> This may not be preferable. Perhaps you’d like to write it using the
>   same syntax as Java. Sadly, you can’t. This is because `:` is not a
>   valid identifier. Fear not, `|` is! Would you settle for this?
>
> ```
> c ? p | q
> ```
>
> Then you’ll need the following code. Notice the call-by-name (`=>`)
>   annotations on the arguments. This evaluation strategy is required to
>   correctly rewrite Java’s ternary operator. This cannot be done in Java
>   itself.
>
> ```
> case class Bool(b: Boolean) {   
>   def ?[X](t: => X) = new {
>     def |(f: => X) = if(b) t else f   
>   } 
> }
>
> object Bool {   
>   implicit def BooleanBool(b: Boolean) = Bool(b) 
> }
> ```
>
> Here is an example using the new operator that we just defined:
>
> ```
> object T {   val condition = true
>
>   import Bool._
>
>   // yay!   
>   val x = condition ? "yes" | "no"
> }
> ```
>
> Have fun ;)

Comment: yes, I have seen this before, but the difference is, that a I have the (evaluated) value of my first expression as an argument in the `then` and `else` clause.

Comment: I took the `if(c) p else q` approach... the lack of braces makes me a touch uncomfortable but that's just a style thing

Answer (score 17):

[Rex Kerr’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947535/ternary-operator-similar-to/4947866#4947866) expressed in basic Scala:

```
"Hi".getClass.getSimpleName match {
  case x if x.endsWith("$") => x.init
  case x => x
}
```

although I’m not sure what part of the if–else construct you want to optimise.

Comment: very straight way. sometimes one forgets about the daily-use match/case statements. I just sticked to the one line ternary `if then else` idiom, but it´s indeed a intelligible way to solve.

Comment: Pattern Matching scales easily to more than two branches.

Answer (score 11):

Since if-else constructions in Scala return a value, you can use this

```
val a = if (1 < 0) 1 else 2
```

More info: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-if-then-ternary-operator-cookbook-examples

Answer (score 0):

Since : by itself won't be a valid operator unless you are ok with always escaping it with back ticks `:`, you could go with another character, e.g. "|" as in one of the answers above. But how about elvis with a goatee ?::

```
implicit class Question[T](predicate: => Boolean) {
  def ?(left: => T) = predicate -> left
}
implicit class Colon[R](right: => R) {
  def ::[L <% R](pair: (Boolean, L)): R = if (q._1) q._2 else right
}
val x = (5 % 2 == 0) ? 5 :: 4.5
```

Of course this again won't work if you values are lists, since they have :: operator themselves.