# "?:" operator is scala

Tags: java, scala, operators

In Java, I can write:

```
Double x = (x1 > x2)? x1:x2
```

But this doesn't seem to work in Scala, the following has an error:

```
var x = (x1 > x2)? x1:x2
```

I don't feel like writing a block of code for this in Scala:

```
var x = x2

if (x1 > x2 ) {
    x = x1
}
```

If there a cleaner way for such operation in Scala? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947535/ternary-operator-similar-to

Comment: I think the answer to that question is way too complex. I actually like the conciseness of the answer here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch03s07.html) and [this](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-ternary-operator-syntax) page you just use the regular if/else syntax:

```
var x = if(x1 > x2) x1 else x2
```