# scala how to mimic a ternary operator in anonymous functions

Tags: scala

I wanted to get "a    e" in the below code by trying to mimic a ternary operator, but getting below error

```
scala> val ab="apple"
ab: String = apple

scala> ab.toCharArray.map( x => "aeiou".indexOf(x) >= 0  )
res99: Array[Boolean] = Array(true, false, false, false, true)

scala> ab.toCharArray.map( x => "aeiou".indexOf(x) >= 0 ? x : ' ' )
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but character literal found.
ab.toCharArray.map( x => "aeiou".indexOf(x) >= 0 ? x : ' ' )
                                                       ^

scala>
```

Comment: You could have first a look at https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-ternary-operator-syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary Operator Similar To ?:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947535/ternary-operator-similar-to)

Comment: @RamanMishra.. No, my question is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid Scala syntax is

```
ab.toCharArray.map(x => if ("aeiou".indexOf(x) >= 0) x else ' ')
```

On contrary

```
ab.chars().map(x -> "aeiou".indexOf(x) >= 0 ? x : ' ');
```

is Java syntax.

Comment: Thanks Dmytro.. I got confused with Java and scala syntax.. it works.